How to deploy an Angular 18 single-page web app to firebase?
UPDATE:
I created a new Angular project and went through the same deployment steps as below without changing anything. It's just the default code for a brand new project.
Then I tried to deploy it, and got the exact same errors as below. ng deploy does nothing at all if I don't select any features to add. That can't be right, can it?
What am I missing? All of this is my first attempt to use Angular, and I haven't intentionally done any kind of global configuration, but is there something I might have done that would explain all this?
I'm completely open to using something other than firebase if it might get me unstuck here.


I have an Angular 18 single page web app that's working locally, and I want to deploy it to Firebase.
I set up a Firebase account, and a project there.
Then:
npm install -g firebase-tools

Then:
ng add @angular/fire

This is where it gets confusing. I get:
% ng add @angular/fire
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1137 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
? What features would you like to setup? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle
 all, <i> to invert selection, and <enter> to proceed)
❯◯ Authentication
 ◯ Google Analytics
 ◯ App Check
 ◯ Firestore
 ◯ Realtime Database
 ◯ Cloud Functions (callable)
 ◯ Cloud Messaging
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)

And if I hit return (since I don't need any of those things), I'm immediately back at the shell prompt. Nothing happens.
If I select "Google Analytics" and then hit return, it asks me to pick my Firebase account (with a deprecation warning about "punycode"), then "Please select a project", which I do, then "Please select an app:".
If I select the app I created via the firebase console, it completes with:
Downloading configuration data of your Firebase WEB app
UPDATE src/app/app.config.ts (2989 bytes)

But if anything happened on Firebase I'm not seeing it. Am I just not looking in the right place?
If I select "[CREATE NEW APP]" instead and give it a name, it completes, and the new app does show up on firebase, but then what?
After doing all of the above I can try ng deploy, but even though ng add @angular/fire completed without giving me an error, I get this:
Cannot find "deploy" target for the specified project.
You can add a package that implements these capabilities.

For example:
  Amazon S3: ng add @jefiozie/ngx-aws-deploy
  Firebase: ng add @angular/fire
  Netlify: ng add @netlify-builder/deploy
  GitHub Pages: ng add angular-cli-ghpages

Would you like to add a package with "deploy" capabilities now? (Use arrow keys)
❯ No
  Amazon S3
  Firebase
  Netlify
  GitHub Pages

And from that point it's the same as above. It returns to the prompt immediately if I don't select any features from the list, and if I do it completes as described above.
What am I missing?

Have you tried using ng deploy and selecting Firebase, without adding the @angular/fire package first? The schematic should install it for you

I'm not sure how to try that, since I've already done ng add @angular/fire and don't see a way to remove it. As mentioned above if I do ng deploy now, it says Cannot find "deploy" target for the specified project and asks me to add a package, and after selecting Firebase everything else is the same as if i try ng add @angular/fire again.

You can revert changes in generated files, which seems it's only src/app/app.config.ts. Then, npm uninstall @angular/fire. And try again with ng deploy + selecting Firebase

I did the uninstall, and reverted app.config.ts. ng deploy found and installed  @angular/fire@18.0.1 and then its the same as before. If I don't select any features it exits immediately, without doing anything as far as I can tell. If I try again and select "google analytics" just to pick one, it asks me to select my firebase account, etc. I selected [CREATE NEW APP] and I can see the new app on my firebase console. All of this is the same as before. Is it successful and I'm just missing something obvious about what to do next?

Okay just did the same and reproduced the issue. The command fails with " ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1." after "✔ Downloading configuration data of your Firebase WEB app" step as in your post. Looks like an issue. Someone has reported this in their repo actually: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3546 Just added a comment with more information

Bummer. If you want to post that as an answer I'll approve it.

Noice! I'll post that then

Just followed your steps and yup, managed to reproduced the error in a clean app & Firebase account
Seems there's an issue with @angular/fire regarding Angular apps deployment initialization with ng deploy. Added some extra information in there to help the team find a fix
Hope it gets fixed soon 
